# Counting distinct undirected paths in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to understand exactly how Cypher returns undirected paths. Here are two queries and their results (they are the same except one uses an undirected pattern):

```
MATCH path = (a)-[]->(b) RETURN count(path), count(distinct(path))
```

count(path):1236951

count(distinct(path)):1236951

```
MATCH path = (a)-[]-(b) RETURN count(path), count(distinct(path))
```

count(path):2473901

count(distinct(path)):2473901

I have two specific questions about this.

a.) Why is *count(path)* in the undirected case not exactly twice what it is in the directed case (it's off by 1)?

b.) In the undirected case, why is *count(distinct(path))* the same as *count(path)*? I would have expected Cypher to match each path twice, once in each direction, and then not count the duplicates in *count(distinct(path))*. Is it not counting the two directions as the same path?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @cybersam! With your query I discovered that one node had one relation to itself, which explains why the number was off by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) I do not have an answer for why the path count for your second query is not exactly double that of your first query (other than a possible bug, or data corruption). However, you should be able to get the relationship(s) that do not have the expected count using the query below. That might provide helpful clues.

```
MATCH path = (a)-[r]-(b)
WITH r, COUNT(*) AS num
WHERE num <> 2
RETURN r;
```

(b) Each "path" consists of an *ordered sequence* of nodes separated by relationships. When you traverse a path in opposite directions, the result is 2 different ordered sequences, which are not equivalent. If you had instead counted distinct relationships, as below, you would have gotten an `nRels` value that is half of `nPaths` (or close to it, taking into account (a)):

```
MATCH path = (a)-[r]-(b)
RETURN count(path) AS nPaths, count(distinct r) AS nRels;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, I'm new to neo4j myself, but in relation to why the undirected path isnt double the directed one, I suspect it has something to do with the direction of the relationships in the graph.

You are querying for a path in any direction but if the graph is directional then a relationship only exists along that direction and so querying a relationship in the opposite direction will return null.

Perhaps the reason the count results are the same is that every relationship defined in your graph has a direction